# i wish to compare 2 numeric values in a column seperate by slash

Tags: awk, sed

If i get an output like below from another command or a file

```
uniquename1: count 2/3
uniquename2: count 3/3
uniquename3: count 1/1
uniquename4: count 3/1
uniquename5: count 0/0
uniquename6: count 1/1
uniquename7: count 1/3
uniquename8: count 2/2
```

How can i compare the numbers surrounding the / on each line.

Where if they match then return a result saying '$uniquename working'

Where if they the numbers do not match then return a result saying '$uniquename warning'

Where if they the first number is 0 then return a result saying '$uniquename broken'

```
uniquename1: warning
uniquename2: working
uniquename3: working
uniquename4: warning
uniquename5: broken
uniquename6: working
uniquename7: warning
uniquename8: working
```

My knowledge is limited and current attempts see me replacing the / then comparing columns 3 and 4 and then printing the name that appears before :
but its a mess and bad

Another way to phrase my need:

The number before the / is actual count

The number after / is expected count

If actual = 0 then its bad

If actual = expected then its good

If actual does not equal 0 or does not equal expected then its not good but not broken

Comment: Please add your current solution.

Comment: In `uniquename7` isn't the correct output `warning`?

Comment: What would be printed if `uniquenameX: count 0/1` and `uniquenameX: count 0/2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
% sed 's%count 0/0%broken%;/ count \(.*\)\/\1$/!s%count .*%warning%;s%count \(.*\)/\1$%working%' file.txt
```

The first section says to swap "count 0/0" with broken (if possible). Second part, after the ";", says if the thing between "count " and "/" does NOT match what comes after "/" then sub in warning. The third part says sub in "working" if they do match.

```
❯ cat /tmp/file.txt
uniquename1: count 2/3
uniquename2: count 3/3
uniquename3: count 1/1
uniquename4: count 3/1
uniquename5: count 0/0
uniquename6: count 1/1
uniquename7: count 1/3
uniquename8: count 2/2
❯ sed 's%count 0/0%broken%;/ count \(.*\)\/\1$/!s%count .*%warning%;s%count \(.\)/\1$%working%' /tmp/file.txt
uniquename1: warning
uniquename2: working
uniquename3: working
uniquename4: warning
uniquename5: broken
uniquename6: working
uniquename7: warning
uniquename8: working
```

I think the sample output does not match my understanding of the question.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Edit.

Comment: This works very nicely and simply, another way to phrase my need is
the first number is actual count
the second number is expected count
if first number 0 then its broken
if first number matches second number then its working
if first number, is not 0, but also does not match second number then its in a warning state

Comment: changed a little 
0/.*%broken%; 
To cover 0/(any number) scenarios

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve your purpose is using `awk` comamnd:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'[:/ ]+' '{
  num1 = $3 + 0
  num2 = $4 + 0
  if (num1 == 0) 
    print $1": broken"
  else if (num1 == num2) 
    print $1": working"
  else 
    print $1": warning"
}'
# Outputs
uniquename1: warning
uniquename2: working
uniquename3: working
uniquename4: warning
uniquename5: broken
uniquename6: working
uniquename7: warning
uniquename8: working
```

**Explanation of the above command:**

1. `The -F'[:/ ]+'` -  This will set the field separator to either a colon (`:`), a slash (`/`), or a space which implies that awk treats **uniquename**, **count**, and the **two numbers** as separate fields.
2. `num1 = \$3 + 0, num2 = \$4 + 0` - Convert the third and fourth fields from the input ($3 and $4, respectively) into numbers.
3. `if (num1 == 0)` - By looking at the current requirement I can surmise that if `num1` is 0 then it's broken. *Based on your other required input you can amend this condition to suit your needs.*

***[CODE DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/hkQxFrxjtu)***

Comment: At this time i'm working with the other good response as it feels easier.
Your code here works as expected too!

Comment: @beastx, cool whichever works best for you is fine. I've added another alternative solution using `awk` in case if you want to give it a try. Cheers:)

Comment: If it were me I'd use `awk` too! :) Something in the original led me to think `sed` was the preferred solution.  `awk` seems more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#count 0/.*#broken#;t;s#count (.*)/\1\b#working#;t;s/count.*/warning/' file
```

If the first count is `0`, replace with `broken` and bail out.

If both counts are the same, replace with `working` and bail out.

Otherwise, replace count with `warning`.